# Erlang hostname illegal when building long name C Node

Tags: c, erlang, interop, distributed-system, erlang-shell

I'm trying to follow the official Erlang C Node tutorial (http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html). I've gotten the short name server and client working, but not the long name server. On the one hand, if I use my computer's host ("stockholm") in `complex4:call_cnode()/1` in `complex4.erl` I get the following error when I call `complex4:foo(3).` in the `erl` CLI:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 20-Mar-2019::12:15:21.400091 ===
** System running to use fully qualified hostnames **
** Hostname stockholm is illegal **
```

On the other hand, if I use any number of alternative hostnames in place of "stockholm" in `complex4.erl`, such as my public IP, my private IP, and a free subdomain I claimed online that maps to my public IP, when I call `complex4:foo(3).` in the CLI the CLI freezes, and the `cserver2` running in the background does not know that anything happened, or throws an `erl_accept` error.

I've tried a number of hacks, including trying to write a custom `.hosts.erlang` containing my subdomain, and using the `-inetrc` flag to add an association between my public IP and my subdomain. I'm using the same cookie everywhere.

Has anyone successfully run the long name server in this tutorial, and, if so, how did you set up your environment to avoid these problems?

Comment: In Erlang node names, a "long name" is a hostname that contains at least one dot, so that's why it rejects `stockholm`. You're getting further with anything that contains a dot, so I'd start looking for the problem at that point.